# How to effectively delete a user as an admin

Tags: php, html, session-cookies

When a user logs in or register, I store a session and cookie and also insert some of the details in database.

**login/register.php**

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = $userid;
$selector = base64_encode(random_bytes(9));
$authenticator = random_bytes(33);
$token = hash('sha256', $authenticator);
$expires = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', time() + 864000);
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO auth_tokens 
(selector,token,userid,expires) VALUES (:selector, :token, :userid, 
:expires)");
$stmt2->bindParam(':selector', $selector);
$stmt2->bindParam(':token', $token);
$stmt2->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
$stmt2->bindParam(':expires', $expires);
$stmt2->execute();

setcookie(
    'remember',
     $selector.':'.base64_encode($authenticator),
     time()+(86400 * 90),
     '/',
     false
);
```

Now, when a user clicks logs out, I destroy the session and cookie

**logout.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION);
if (isset($_COOKIE['remember'])) {
unset($_COOKIE['remember']);
setcookie('remember', '', time() - 3600, '/'); // empty value and old 
timestamp
}
session_destroy();
```

As an admin, I want to delete a user session and cookie when I delete the user from my own End.

Right now when I delete a user in the database using this

**deleteuser.php**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM users WHERE id=:uid");
$stmt->bindValue(':uid', $uid);
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt){ 
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM auth_tokens WHERE userid=:uid");
$stmt2->bindValue(':uid', $uid);
$stmt2->execute();
}
```

When thesame user re visits a page(index.php), I get this error at the top of the page

**Warning: hash_equals(): Expected known_string to be a string, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\book\php\function.php on line 17**

**index.php**

```
include('php/function.php');
getcookie();
```

**function.php**

```
if (!empty($_COOKIE['remember'])) {
list($selector, $authenticator) = explode(':', $_COOKIE['remember']);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM auth_tokens WHERE selector=:selector");
$stmt->bindValue(':selector', $selector);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if (hash_equals($row['token'], hash('sha256',
base64_decode($authenticator)))) {
.....
}
}

function getcookie (){

if (!empty($_COOKIE['remember'])) {
    list($selector, $authenticator) = explode(':', $_COOKIE['remember']);
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM auth_tokens WHERE 
 selector=:selector");
    $stmt->bindValue(':selector', $selector);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    $toke = $row['token'];
    $auth = hash('sha256', base64_decode($authenticator));       
    if (hash_equals($row['token'], hash('sha256',
    base64_decode($authenticator)))) {
    $userid = $row['userid'];
    // Then regenerate login token as above
    }
 }
}
```

How do I tweak these codes so that I can effectively delete a user from my website by ending the users session and cookie.?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the user's session/cookie on their side... but what you can do is immediately remove their ability to do anything admin-ish.

If the user's credentials are re-checked on the server (based on their sessionID or whatever) prior to any admin-level action, then their admin status is effectively disabled - and you would then transfer them to a non-admin screen at the same time.

You might ask: What if they have the admin screen up and active when I nuke them? There is little you can do about a static screen (they can take a screenshot - you cannot prevent that). They can hit the back button and perhaps view a screen from cache. But

Some possible solutions are:

(a) Use ajax with a setInterval (or recursive setTimeout) function to re-check their admin credentials with the server every X seconds/minutes. Then, even if they are afk they can be logged out of the admin screen. *(Of course, this method can be halted by a savvy user by monkeying in DevTools.)*

(b) Before any admin action is executed, their creds are re-checked. If they are no longer an admin, the action is refused AND they are returned to a non-admin screen. This method cannot be interfered with by a savvy user.

Won't this introduce a noticeable delay to everything?

No. Re-checking the creds is as simple as live-checking their user-privilege status in your database.

When you de-adminize them, you will change their priv level, so this will be picked up immediately whenever the user tries to do something from that admin screen. Unless you have several thousand users, don't worry about the overhead of doing this. Even with several thousand users, it is still probably a decent way of handling the matter. You are communicating with the server at this point anyway, and within each admin-action function, just insert a quick check to "verify admin status" - so it is just back-end code on the server communicating with its own database. Super quick.

Comment: I am the only admin in the website. I am only trying to delete a normal user. Can you share codes on how to check if that user session or cookie still exist in my database....and how to get rid of it and how to get rid of that error - hash_equals(): Expected known_string to be a string, null given. It is returning a null value.

Comment: What is your server side config? Is it PHP / MySQL? Shared server or private server or VPS or ? If shared server with MySQL, then you can use PHPMyAdmin (from CPANEL) to view the database tables. If VPS or private, is it a Linux-based LAMP stack, or Micro$oft? If Linux, you should have PHPMyAdmin app and you can use that to look at the tables directly. To check the database, you can either use code -OR- you can do so directly, by looking at the tables, with PHPMyAdmin or equivalent.

Comment: Looking again at your question, you have PHP and probably are using MySQL (aka MariaDb). So, use PHPMyAdmin and look in the users table to get his userid, then look in the auth_tokens table to find the auth_token with the same user_id. Delete all auth_tokens with his user_id. No need to write code to do this, just do it yourself with PHPMyAdmin. If you are unfamiliar, you can install xampp on your local machine (installs Apache web server, PHP, MySQL, PHPMyAdmin, etc) and play with it. Do a tutorial on creating a login system using PHP and MySQL - you will be an expert within a few hours.